# PUG: Why am I getting "Assigning to rvalue" error when trying to compile href="#"?

Tags: pug

I'm working with PUG in Angular 11 and was surprised by the error it threw while converting them to PUG regarding commonly used href="#".  Does anyone know why?

```
Error: src/app/core/components/navbar/navbar.component.pug:20:38
  > 20|       a.navbar-toggle.collapsed(href="#" (click)="logout()" style="color: #FFF;")
---------------------------------------------^
    21|         md-tooltip(md-direction="top") Log out
    22|         span.glyphicon.glyphicon-log-out
    23| 

Syntax Error: Assigning to rvalue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in Pug documentation -- I had to put a comma or wrap the subsequent (click) in quotes.

https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html

> If your attribute name contains odd characters that might interfere
> with JavaScript syntax, either quote it using "" or '', or use commas
> to separate different attributes. Examples of such characters include
> [] and () (frequently used in Angular 2).